# New collection or nested array?

Tags: mongodb

Supposed we have a db called A. The structure of A can be:

1) A( a, b, c, d).

a, b, c, d are collections.

And the element in each collection is like { _id:id, data : data }

2) A(k).

k(a, b, c, d)

k is a colletion. and a, b, c, d are elements inside k.

a, b, c, d are like

```
{
    type : 'a / b / c / d', 
    data : [ 
        {_id : id1, data : data1 }, 
        {_id : id2, data : data2},
        ... 
    ]
}
```

the daily operations are { get, inserting element into, empty element of } a, b, c and d.

Which one is better in terms of efficiency?

Comment: This is - by far - too abstract. The difference between RDBMS and NoSQL databases is that within the former you ask "What questions can be answered by this data model?" whereas with NoSQL you model your data according to the questions you have (a subtle difference). Please describe your actual use case.

Answer (score 1):

**@Markus-W-Mahlberg** is right about your **actual-use-case**.

As you are using mongodb and it uses documents not tabular data structure (such as ms-sql), your both approaches work fine and if you define right index, u get same performance.
But in my opinion if your types (a, b, c and d ) have different structures (different properties, different **queries**, different update scenarios, aggregation plans and ...) Use **way1**, other wise use Way2 with right index.